# Cannot invoke 'async' with an argument list of type '(execute: ())'

Tags: swift, afnetworking

I am trying to make a network call, then update the main thread, but it seems that any variable created in the background thread can not be sent as a parameter to the main thread:

```
 let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,
                                completionHandler: {
                                    (data, response, error) in
                                    guard let _:Data=data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {


                                        return
                                    }

                                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])


    var car = "hello"
    DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: self.someFunc(car)) <-- wont accept car parameter

    })

    task.resume()
```

here is the signature:

```
func someFunc( str:String) {

}
```

getting the following error:
Cannot invoke 'async' with an argument list of type '(execute: ())'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: () -> Void)
```

expects a closure without parameter.

---

Use the syntax

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { someFunc(str: car) })
```

or with trailing closure syntax

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.someFunc(str: car)
}
```

and don't forget the label parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the label from your function by using `_` before the name of it. An example:

```
func doSomething ( _ str : String ) {}
```

> This allows you to call the function like this `doSomething("text")`

If you don't use the underscore you have to say `doSomething(str : "")` when you call the function